# How to correctly put test suites in functions in mocha?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm fairly new to mocha, I've been working with it over the summer to write dynamic test cases for a feature in a web application. Basically I can send a request and get all the possible values I can send. So I've been using that to loop through and test everything. To make that easier I created a function with the test suite and a few variables that should let it run all the tests. It kind of works, by that I mean it correctly runs all the tests. However, it waits till after everything else has run for some reason, which causes some issues with what I'm trying to do.
I've simplified what I'm trying to do down to some really basic code:

```
function test(){
    //Testing suite to test through a certain functionality using different variables
    describe('inner',function(){
        it('test3',function(){
            console.log('\ninner test');
        });
    });
}
function entityLoop() {
    describe('outer',function(){
        //Get field values from an http request
        it('test1',function(){
            console.log('\ntest1');
        });
        it('test2',function(){
            console.log('\ntest2');
        });

        //This MUST run after the other two tests, as those tests get the values needed to run the following tests
        //I know it's typically bad practice to make dependent tests, but that's how we're dynamically creating the tests
        after(function(){
            //Use field values in a testing suite
            console.log('after test');
            test();
        })
    })
}

describe("Overall loop",function(){
    //Need to loop through a testing suite, changing some variables each time
    for(var i = 0; i < 5;i++){
        entityLoop();
    }

});
```

And here's the output that I get from it:

```
test1
test2
after test
test1
test2
after test
test1
test2
after test
test1
test2
after test
test1
test2
after test
inner test
inner test
inner test
inner test
inner test
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I don't understand why 'inner test' is outputted 5 times in a row at the end, instead of right after 'after test' each time. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is calling `describe` and `it` from inside an `after` hook. It does not crash the test suite but **it is not a usage pattern that is explicitly supported by Mocha.** So it does not do what you expect it to do.

You get the results you are getting because `describe(name, fn)` does this:

> Create a test suite named `name`. Add it to the suite that is currently being defined. Push the new suite on the suite stack. Call `fn`. Pop the suite stack.

The "suite that is currently being defined" is the one at the top of the suite stack. Mocha maintains a stack of suites. It initially contains a top-level implicit suite that Mocha creates to contain all tests. (So you could have a test file that does not use `describe` at all and it would still work because all the tests would be defined on this implicit top-level suite.)

And `it(name, fn)` does this:

> Create a test named `name` and with callback `fn`. Add it to the suite currently being defined.

If you trace mentally what is going on with your code when it runs, you'll find that when the code in `after` runs, the "suite currently being defined" is the top-level implicit suite that Mocha creates by default to contain all tests. (It has no name. If you add `after(function () { console.log("after overall loop"); })` to your top level `describe`, you'll see that all the `inner test` outputs appear after the `after overall loop` output.)

So your `after` hook is adding new tests to the top-level implicit suite. They necessarily run after all your tests because they are added at the end of the suite.

Comment: Ahhhh, I was wondering if that was the case. Since this isn't really a supported feature, do you happen to know of any other ways to dynamically create a whole suite? I was looking at the mocha docs and another stack overflow question and those answers don't seem like they'll work for me, as they were just a couple dynamically created it's instead of a whole suite.

Comment: You want to make some tests dependent on other tests. This is a problem, no matter whether the suite is built dynamically or not.

Comment: The issue is I'm not sure how to do it otherwise. I'm dynamically building the tests based on values I have to pull from the server. It has to be dependent